# Question about "cv" parameter in sklear model and Kfold()

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, hyperparameter

It may sounds like a silly question but let's take the [RidgeCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html) model from sklearn.linear_model. This one has the parameter "cv".

> cv : int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional
>
> Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy. Possible inputs for cv are:
>
> - None, to use the efficient Leave-One-Out cross-validation (also known as Generalized Cross-Validation).
> - integer, to specify the number of folds.
> - CV splitter,
> - An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.
>
> For integer/None inputs, if y is binary or multiclass, sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold is used, else, sklearn.model_selection.KFold is used.

My question is the following: Why do we have to call KFold() when the parameter 'cv' is already performing a k-fold ? (if integer specified)

To make it clearer, why do we have this:

```py
kfolds = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
ridge = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas_alt, cv=kfolds)
```

And not only this ?

```py
ridge = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas_alt, cv=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it, it is still OK. In the second one, `shuffle` option for `KFold` will be `False`, and you won't be able to set `random_state` in order for your analysis to be reproducible. Sometimes, it's more convenient to manage the splitter object at a greater detail, which is the case for the first usage.